# Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, html, login

Aquí el código, la verdad es que no entiendo por qué salta error, la conexión está bien hecha. En la base de datos no hay problema alguno, el Inicio de Sesión está bien, lo único que salta error es esto, quizá sea el mysqli pero no tengo idea. Sería de gran ayuda si alguien puede ayudarme.

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST["boton"])) {
     if ($_POST['contraseña'] == $_POST['contraseña2']) {

include "conexion.php" ;
            $user= $_POST['user'];    
            $nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
            $apellido= $_POST['apellido'];
            $contraseña= $_POST['contraseña'];
            $contraseña2= $_POST['contraseña2'];

   $pass = sha1(md5($contraseña));  


    mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios (id_user, nombre,apellido,contraseña_us,) VALUES($user, '$nombre', '$apellido','$contraseña') ") or die($conexion."problemas en la verificacion de datos"); 
        


    echo "<script>alert('Registro exitoso');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location='index.php';</script>";
        }else{
    echo "<script>alert('Las contraseñas no coinciden');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location='registro.php';</script>";
    
    }
 }
   

?>
```

Comment: Prueba a asignar el resultado de `mysqli_query` y luego compáralo con un `if`, en vez de mezclarlo con un `or die()`, el error se debe a que aquí: `die($conexion....)` intentas usar la conexión como una cadena. También revisa tu consulta SQL, tiene errores.

Comment: te falta las ' ' en values para user osea `VALUES ('$user',....)`

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es porque aquí: `die($conexion."problemas en la verificacion de datos")` estás usando la conexión, que es un objeto, en una concatenación, como si fuese una cadena.

Aparte de eso tienes un eror en la consulta SQL, te sobra una coma.

Prueba así:

```
if (mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios (id_user, nombre,apellido,contraseña_us) VALUES($user, '$nombre', '$apellido','$contraseña'")) {
    #Aquí mensaje de éxito ... sería mejor redirección, porque veo otras redirecciones
} else {
    #Aquí mensaje de consulta errónea ... sería mejor redirección, porque veo otras redirecciones
}
```

Recomendaría que evites el uso de `die()` y que des coherencia a todo el código. Si estás implementando redirecciones, entonces redirige también cuando la consulta falle, no lo resuelvas con un simple `die`, dejando el flujo del código en un limbo.

También, tu consulta es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*, deberías blindar el código usando **consultas preparadas**.